# Should we normalize a quantitative co-variable before inputing in a cox model (survival analysis)?

Tags: survival

I am computing survival analyses of a case-control study.
The outcome is graft loss : yes or not - with right censoring

My cohort is divided in three clusters and I would like to see if there is a difference in survival depending on these clusters (*mydata$HCPC_clust* - categorical variables : K1,K2,K3), while taking into account (adjust?) a quantitative variable : the time post-transplant where the case diagnosis has been made (*P_t_J0_de_la_transplant_mois*).

My code is this one :

```r
result = coxph(mydata.surv~ as.factor(mydata$HCPC_clust) + 
               mydata$P_t_J0_de_la_transplant_mois_)
```

My model seems ok, with regard to the proportionality (I didn't test the log-linearity though)

```r
test.mydata <- cox.zph(result, transform=c("km"), global=TRUE )

                                        chisq df    p
as.factor(mydata$HCPC_clust)         0.5298  2 0.77
mydata$P_t_J0_de_la_transplant_mois_ 0.0178  1 0.89
GLOBAL                               0.7840  3 0.85
```

My question is : Should I normalize/scale the quantitative covariate "*P_t_J0_de_la_transplant_mois*" before inputting it in my model ?

Right now, the variable "*P_t_J0_de_la_transplant_mois*" do not come as a significant factor whereas the clusters 2 and 3 have an increase risk of graft loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling or normalizing the continuous quantitative covariate won't affect the substance of the model or the "significance" of that covariate. That would change the value of the point estimate of the regression coefficient, but it would also correspondingly change the standard error of the estimate. A Cox regression isn't fundamentally different from other regressions in that regard.

Keeping that predictor in its current units of months is much easier to understand than what you would get with the R `scale()` function. If you scale by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation, you get standard-deviation units for the predictor instead. How do you think about standard-deviation units? How would you apply those units to new data?

You are, however, assuming that there is a simple linear relation between log-hazard and the value of that predictor. It might be wise to model that predictor more flexibly, for example with a restricted cubic spline. That might elucidate a more subtle association of that predictor with outcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It was exactly what I was wondering :)