# Should you normalize covariates in a linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, normalization, batch-normalization

I am using `lmer` for a set of mixed models, each comparing a protein quantity of interest with a biomarker. Even after experimental batch correction & normalization for the proteins, these are still skewed distributions and not on comparable scales, so for those explanatory variables I am using inverse rank normalization so that the proteins will be scaled/distributed for comparable betas.

`biomarker ~ covA + covB + covC + prot`

Included with each will be several fixed covariates (some quantitative some categorical), and I believe there is no reason to normalize those, but haven't been able to find a useful resource confirming under what conditions (if ever) covariates need to be scaled/normalized. As I understand it that would only impact the error/residuals? Similar to the description here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/554726/196677

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to normalise for "comparable betas" as you write, even though this is not without its pitfalls. However nothing in the model setup or estimator theory requires "comparable betas" or normalised covariates. Standard estimation methods are affine equivariant meaning that they will behave accordingly if you transform covariates linearly; meaning that technically results will be equivalent and it doesn't matter whether you normalise or not. (It is conceivable but rather exceptional that scale differences are so large that they lead to numerical issues with the algorithms.)

By the way, there is no assumption that stops you from using skewly distributed covariates either (although they may occasionally give extreme observations too much influence).